# Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) returns null value

Tags: asp.net, url

I'm trying to get the base of url using the following command : 
`string baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);` which returns a null value. `Request.RequestUri` returns `http://10.71.34.1:63026/api/member/profilethumb/PetePentreath` but I only want `http://10.71.34.1:63026/` and the rest of the url chopped off. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cause `Uri.Scheme`, `Uri.Host` and `Uri.Port` property to build your output. You can also use `UriBuilder` class and get the required `Uri` like:

```
Uri RequestUri = Request.RequestUri;
Uri modifiedUri = new UriBuilder(RequestUri.Scheme, RequestUri.Host,RequestUri.Port).Uri;
```

`modifiedUri` will have `http://10.71.34.1:63026/`

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba, glad it worked for you, not sure why `Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` didn't work, it should have. \